# Replace the connection string in the web.config with msdeploy

Tags: powershell, xpath, msdeploy, webdeploy

I want to replace the connectionString in the web.config of a hosted iis service at a remote computer with msdeploy and powershell.

The script runs without errors:

```
 $iisPath = "$iisServicePath,computerName=$computerName,userName=$userName,password=$password"

 & "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" `
"-source=contentPath=$iisPath" `
'-verb=sync' `
'-verbose' `
'-allowUntrusted' `
"-dest=contentPath=$iisPath" ` 
'-setParam=kind=TextFile,match="configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name=MyEntities]/@connectionString",scope=web\.config$,value="$newConString"';
```

The verbose output of the script says:

```
Verbose: The synchronization completed in 1 pass(es).
Total changes: 0 (0 added, 0 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
```

The connectionString Attribute`s value was not replaced.

How can I do that?

UPDATE

That is the error message I get now:

```
Verbose: Parameter entry 'MSDeploySetParameter-2080747909/1' could not be applied to 'MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config'. Deployment will continue with the original data. Details:
No matches were found for the search string '`"configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name=MyEntities]/@connectionString`' (type 'TextFile').
Verbose: Attribute 'size' equality changed to False when comparing filePath (MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config) to MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config because of rule Parameterizat
ion.
Verbose: Source filePath (MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config) does not match destination (MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config) differing in attributes (parameters). Update pending.
Verbose: Source filePath (MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config) replaced with changed attributes (size['3710','3707']) because of rule Parameterization.
Info: Updating file (MyWebSite/MyService\Web.config).
Verbose: The dependency check 'DependencyCheckInUse' found no issues.
Verbose: The synchronization completed in 2 pass(es).
Total changes: 1 (0 added, 0 deleted, 1 updated, 0 parameters changed, 3707 bytes copied)
```

With this changed code:

```
 & "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" `
"-source=contentPath=$iisPath" `
'-verb=sync' `
'-verbose' `
'-allowUntrusted' `
"-dest=contentPath=$iisPath" `
'-setParam=kind=TextFile,match=`"configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name=MyEntities]/@connectionString`",scope=web\.config$,value=`"$newConString`"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line here, you're using single quotes, which will be interpretted exactly as typed (so it wouldn't swap in the value for a variable, for instance)

I've replaced your single quotes with double, and gone ahead and escaped the inner quotes as well.  If this doesn't work, let me know!

```
-setParam=kind=TextFile,match=`"configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name=MyEntities]/@connectionString`",scope=web\.config$,value=`"$newConString`" ";
```